# What is the 'Knife-only' combat map called in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I played with a friend a few months ago on a knife-only combat server. However I can't seem to find what this map/mode is.

What is this called?

Comment: Are you asking for the name of that specific server? Or the name of the map?

Comment: Asking for the name of the minigame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knife only maps generally start with `ka` or `35hp`.

If you look for maps that start with one of these you will likely find other knife only servers, or at the very least a server which has knife only maps in it's rotation.